# Plotting arrows perpendicular to coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a plot like this, plotting a semicircle with x and y
[image]

I want to add arrows at each point like so (ignore the horrible paint job):
[image]

Is there an easy way to add arrows perpendicular to the plot?

Current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2
h = 0
k = 0

x0 = h-r
x1 = h+r

x = np.linspace(x0,x1,9)
y = k + np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.ylim(-4,4)
```

***PERPENDICULAR TO THE TANGENT OF THE CURVE I'M SORRY I FORGOT TO ADD THIS***

Answer (score 1):

A point in space has no idea what "perpendicular" means, but assuming your y is some function of x that has a derivate, you can think of the derivate of the function at some point to be the tangent of the curve at that point, and to get a perpendicular vector you just need to rotate the vector counter-clockwise 90 degrees:

`x1, y1 = -y0, x0`

Answer (score 1):

We know that these points come from a circle. So given three points we can easily find the center using basic geometry notions. If you need a refresher, take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213658/get-the-equation-of-a-circle-when-given-3-points).

For this particular case, the center is at the origin. Knowing the center coordinates, the normal at each point is just the vector from the center to the point itself. Since the center is the origin, the normals' components are just given by the coordinates of the points themselves.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2
h = 0
k = 0

x0 = h-r
x1 = h+r

x = np.linspace(x0, x1, 9)
y = k + np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)
center = np.array([0.0, 0.0])

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.quiver(x, y, x, y, width=0.005)
plt.xlim(-4, 4)
plt.ylim(-4, 4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you are in a hurry and you do not have time to implement equations, you could use the [scikit-spatial](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library in the following way:

```py
from skspatial.objects import Circle, Vector, Points

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2
h = 0
k = 0

x0 = h-r
x1 = h+r

x = np.linspace(x0, x1, 9)
y = k + np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)
points = Points(np.vstack((x, y)).T)
circle = Circle.best_fit(np.vstack((x, y)).T)
center = circle.point
normals = np.array([Vector.from_points(center, point) for point in points])
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.quiver(x, y, normals[:, 0], normals[:, 1], width=0.005)
plt.xlim(-4, 4)
plt.ylim(-4, 4)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Postulate of blunova's and simon's answers is correct, generally speaking: points have no normal, but curve have; so you need to rely on what you know your curve is. Either, as blunova described it, by the knowledge that it is a circle, and computing those normal with ad-hoc computation from that knowledge.

Or, as I am about to describe, using the function f such as `y=f(x)`. and using knowledge on what is the normal to such a (x,f(x)) chart.

Here is your code, written with such a function f

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2
h = 0
k = 0

x0 = h-r
x1 = h+r
x = np.linspace(x0,x1,9)

def f(x):
   return k + np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)
y=f(x)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.ylim(-4,4)
```

So, all I did here is rewriting your line `y=...` in the form of a function.

From there, it is possible to compute the normal to each point of the chart (x,f(x)).

The tangent to a point (x,f(x)) is well known: it is vector (1,f'(x)), where f'(x) is the derivative of f. So, normal to that is (-f'(x), 1).
Divided by √(f'(x)²+1) to normalize this vector.

So, just use that as entry to quiver.

First compute a derivative of your function

```py
dx=0.001
def fprime(x):
    return (f(x+dx)-f(x-dx))/(2*dx)
```

Then, just

```py
    plt.quiver(x, f(x), -fprime(x), 1)
```

Or, to have all vector normalized

```py
    plt.quiver(x, f(x), -fprime(x)/np.sqrt(fprime(x)**2+1), 1/np.sqrt(fprime(x)**2+1))
```

(note that fprime and the normalization part are all vectorizable operation, so it works with x being a `arange`)

All together

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2
h = 0
k = 0

x0 = h-r
x1 = h+r


def f(x):
    return k+ np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)

dx=0.001
x = np.linspace(x0+dx,x1-dx,9)
y = f(x)
def fprime(x):
    return (f(x+dx)-f(x-dx))/(2*dx)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.quiver(x,f(x), -fprime(x)/np.sqrt(fprime(x)**2+1), 1/np.sqrt(fprime(x)**2+1))

plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.ylim(-4,4)
plt.show()
```

That is almost an exact copy of your code, but for the `quiver` line, and with the addition of `fprime`.
One other slight change, specific to your curve, is that I changed x range to ensure the computability of fprime (if first x is x0, then fprime need f(x0-dx) which does not exist because of sqrt. Likewise for x1. So, first x is x0+dx, and last is x1-dx, which is visually the same)

[image]

That is the main advantage of this solution over blunova's: it is your code, essentially. And would work if you change `f`, without assuming that `f` is a circle. All that is assume is that f is derivable (and if it were not, you could not define what those normal are anyway).

For example, if you want to do the same with a parabola instead, just change f

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2
h = 0
k = 0

x0 = h-r
x1 = h+r


def f(x):
    return x**2

dx=0.001
x = np.linspace(x0+dx,x1-dx,9)
y = f(x)
def fprime(x):
    return (f(x+dx)-f(x-dx))/(2*dx)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.quiver(x,f(x), -fprime(x)/np.sqrt(fprime(x)**2+1), 1/np.sqrt(fprime(x)**2+1))

plt.xlim(-4,4)
plt.ylim(-2,5)
plt.show()
```

All I changed here is the f formula. Not need for a new reasoning to compute the normal.
[image]

Last remark: an even more accurate version (not forcing the approximate computation of fprime with a `dx`) would be to use sympy to define `f`, and then compute the real, symbolic, derivative of `f`. But that doesn't seem necessary for your case.